# `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials` during setup of LDAP server on Centos 7 VM

Tags: openldap, centos7

I am setting up an LDAP server on a centos 7 VM, by [following the guide here](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=1).

Everything is fine until the last part of step 4, after I create the base domain. I have not changed `ldap.conf` or similar files.

When I run the `ldapadd` command:

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=srv,dc=world -W -f basedomain.ldif
```

(This is the [end of step 4](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=1)) I get:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

I did set `dc=localhost,dc=localdomain` which matches the `localhost.localdomain` hostname of my VM.

I have basically followed the tutorial to the letter, up to this step. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: How does your problem compare with similar answers, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573108/ldap-bind-invalid-credentials-49), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218882/enter-ldap-password-keeps-saying-ldap-bind-invalid-credentials-49)?  Or those in the related links to the right?   It's good to state that context when you have a complex question like this, so that others can understand what is not possible here, and why.

Comment: I have seen both. I have not configured slapd.conf as it is not in the guidelines and I have also read that it is done dynamically with newer versions. Of course I may have done it the first time around when I first doing the guideline and it eventually worked, I was having the same problem.

Comment: It's a good idea to update this question with what you have done to isolate the issue.  It will help someone offer advice about where the issue does/may lie.

Comment: I am also using Centos 7 minimal as the OS

Comment: I do have one possibility: When I modify  olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif     The olcRootPW is not in this format {SSHA}ut1NUD85/BZ5d7qt2NgKNQiOwMaVYcn9 but rather  this for format olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9dXQxTlVEODUvQlo1ZDdxdDJOZ0tOUWlPd01hVlljbjk= Could it be that modification is not done correctly?

Comment: By manually entering the olcRootPW value seems to have fixed the problem of step 4.

Comment: If you solved the issue then you should post an answer and explain how the solution worked.  It will help future people.

Comment: How do you post the answer, just as an edit or is there a format to it. I just pressed the * does that mean the problem is solved.